# How can you check battery cell noise using oscilloscope

Tags: batteries, oscilloscope

I want to power a photodiode and it outputs current in the region of nA. I am using Rigol DS4034 oscillator but I am having noise issues generated by ground loop. To solve this I want to power the photodiode using battery cells.

How can I test noise of LiPo or 9V batteries?

Can I just hook positive and negative sides of battery to the oscilloscope using BNC and crocodile cable? Can this generate high current in the ground of oscillator?

After checking isolated oscilloscope questions asked by others, I want to test batteries without blowing the oscilloscope.

Comment: *Rigol DS4034 oscillator* Perhaps you mean **oscilloscope**. Oscilloscopes measure **voltages**, not currents so you need to convert the current into a voltage using a resistor or a transimpedance amplifier. You should not be using direct BNC connections to the oscilloscope, use a **probe** and then you also run minimal risk of blowing up the scope. But really, you will need a  transimpedance amplifier because a nA is not a lot.

Comment: um, stupid question: Why do you think a battery causes a relevant amount of noise for your application? Is this really what you *should* be measuring? I can't think of many elements in a circuit that would have *less* noise than a battery.

Comment: If you understand what causes people to blow up their oscilloscopes with the ground connection, then you will understand whether or not you are doing it.

Comment: Sounds like an X Y problem.  Battery noise is almost certainly not the problem with your system.

Answer (score 2):

You won't likely be able to see any noise from the battery on an oscilloscope because the noise floor of the oscilloscope is too large.

To actually make a useful measurement, you'll likely need to use (eg. SR560) or make a low-noise AC-coupled amplifier that covers the bandwidth of interest.

Provided you stay within the limits the oscilloscope is rated for (typically marked on the oscilloscope front or back panel) you won't damage the oscilloscope.